# Need solution to display an image coming from the backend to the frontend

Tags: image, mern

I need a solution or at least a tip for my problem in which I have been stuck quite a long time. So I want to retrieve an image which is coming from the backend through an http request(2 Images , 2 requests). I have used .map() for the text data to be displayed , but how can I use it for inserting the relevant images?
(And I don't think the image can be stored in an array as I have done below)
The 2 images should be in CardImg component and the other should be sent as a prop to another component.

The images are obtained by ID of the collection. Below is the frontend code.

```
import {Card , CardImg , CardBody , CardTitle , CardText , Button } from 'reactstrap';
import {useState} from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import ItineraryContainer from 'components/ItineraryContainer';
import Backdrop from 'components/ItineraryBackdrop';
import styles from '../assets/css/Itinerary.module.css'
import axios from 'axios';
        
function Itineraries(){
    
    const [itineraries , setItineraries] = useState([]);
    const [itineraryImage , setItineraryImage] = useState([]);
    const [itineraryCovImage , setCovImage] = useState ([]); 

    useEffect(() =>{
        axios.get("http://localhost:8070/itineraries/").then((res)=>{
            setItineraries(res.data);
            console.log(res.data);
            
            itineraries.map((i) =>{
                const id = i._id;
        
                    axios.get(`http://localhost:8070/itineraries/getImage/${id}`).then((r)=>{
                        itineraryImage.push(r.data);
                   
                    }).catch((err) =>{
                        console.log(err);
                    })
                
                    axios.get(`http://localhost:8070/itineraries/getCovImage/${id}`).then((r) =>{
                        itineraryCovImage.push(r.data);
                  
                    }).catch((err) =>{
                        console.log(err);
                    })
        
        
            })


        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err);
        })
    } , []);






    const [ItineraryisOpen , setItineraryOpen] = useState(false);
    function ViewItinerary(){
            setItineraryOpen(true);
    }

    function ItineraryisClosed(){
        setItineraryOpen(false);
    }
    return(
        <div>   
            <div className = {styles.Packages}>
                <h3>Our Tours</h3>
                <br/><br/>
                <div className = {styles.container} >
                {itineraries.map((itinerary) =>(
                        
                    <Card style = {{width: '20rem' , margin : '50px'}}>
                    <CardImg  top src = "img.jpg" alt = "TourImage" />
                    <CardBody>
                        <CardTitle>{itinerary.itineraryName}</CardTitle>
                        <CardText>
                        {itinerary.itineraryDesc}<br/><br/>
                            <b>Itinerary Days  : {itinerary.itineraryDays} </b>
                            <b>Itinerary Class : {itinerary.itineraryClass}</b>
                            <b>Price Per Adult : {itinerary.itineraryPriceAdult}  </b> <br/>
                            <b>Price per Child : {itinerary.itineraryPriceChild} </b>

                        </CardText>

                        <Button color = "primary" onClick = {ViewItinerary} >View Itinerary</Button>
                        <Button color = "info" style = {{float : 'right'}}>Book Tour</Button>
                    </CardBody>        

                    </Card>
                 
                ))}
                </div>
                
                {ItineraryisOpen ? <ItineraryContainer onCancel = {ItineraryisClosed}/> : null}
                {ItineraryisOpen && <Backdrop onCancel = {ItineraryisClosed}/>}
                
                
                
            </div>

        </div>
    );
}

export default Itineraries;
```

Below is the code for the routes

```
//Fetch one Itinerary Image

router.route("/getImage/:id").get(async(req,res)=>{
    const itinerary = req.params.id;
    const itin = await Itinerary.findById(itinerary).then((data)=>{
        const image = data.itineraryImage;
        const file = `./images/${image}`;
        res.download(file);
        
        
    }).catch((err)=>{
        res.status(500).send({status : "Fetching Image unsuccesful!"});
    })
})


//Fetch one Itinerary Cover Image

router.route("/getCovImage/:id").get(async(req,res)=>{
    const itinerary = req.params.id;
    const itin = await Itinerary.findById(itinerary).then((data)=>{
        const image = data.itineraryCoverImage;
        const file = `./images/${image}`;
        res.download(file);
        
        
    }).catch((err)=>{
        res.status(500).send({status : "Fetching Image unsuccesful!"});
    })
})
```

(The backend gives the image as response , checked using postman).
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I have made things complicated. I directly used the HTTP request for the src attribute and it works! (Removed all the code inside the useEffect except for the "itinerary")

**This did the job.**

```
<CardImg  top src = {`http://localhost:8070/itineraries/getImage/${itinerary._id}`}
```